# Order types in different columns table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sqlite

This is a general question and does not have any relation to specific programming code.
However, this sounds simple, but I can not manage to figure it out.

Giving the following DB structure:

```
id  |  name   |  type
1   |  testA  |   A
2   |  testA  |   A
3   |  testA  |   A
4   |  testB  |   B
5   |  testB  |   B
```

from this i want to generate table that would look like this:

HTML TABLE:

```
Col A   Col B
testA   testB
testA   testB
testA
```

so the html code would looks like:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Col A</th>
     <th>Col B</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>testA</td>
     <td>testB</td>
   <tr>
   <tr>
     <td>testA</td>
     <td>testB</td>
   <tr>
   <tr>
     <td>testA</td>
     <td></td>
   <tr>
<table>
```

Although, if you have some solution using inline `colspan` and `rowspan` it is also welcome.

I could not find an elegant solution.

My code so far is:

```
// Not Working:

$elements = array('doc'=>array(),'pub'=>array());
$db = new SQLite3('sqlite3.db');
$results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM l ORDER BY type;');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($elements[$row['type']], $row);
}
$fi = array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($elements['pub'])+count($elements['doc']);$i++){
    if ($i%2==0){
        array_push($fi,$elements['pub'][floor($i/2)]);
    }else{
        array_push($fi,$elements['doc'][floor($i/2)]);
    }
}
var_dump($fi);
exit();
// This is not working because most of the times 
// the count of elements from type A
// is NOT equal to elements of type B.
```

Comment: can you give me more information

Comment: What more information?

Comment: What is ColA and what colB if colB is type then where it's stored.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite? Question is tagged with both.

Comment: Why is that matter? its basic DB..

Comment: Throw all rows in a multidimensional if they're in first or second colation of table and then loop the new array. `$new = array("a" => array(), "b" => array());`

Comment: I can post a more specific answer with code later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no connection between the A/B values in the same row, so we have to invent one.
This can be done by using the [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)s of newly inserted rows (the SELECT just does a full outer join):

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempA AS
SELECT name FROM l WHERE type = 'A';

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempB AS
SELECT name FROM l WHERE type = 'B';

SELECT tempA.name, tempB.name
FROM tempA
LEFT JOIN tempB USING (rowid)
UNION ALL
SELECT tempA.name, tempB.name
FROM tempB
LEFT JOIN tempA USING (rowid)
WHERE tempA.name IS NULL;

DROP TABLE tempA;
DROP TABLE tempB;
```